# ArcGIS 10.5 subtype and domains in database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5

I can not find ArcGIS domains and subtypes of feature classes in my database table (PostgreSQL 9.5, postgis 2.2).

For example I have a domain named `material types`:

- 1  PVC
- 2  IRON
- 3  HDPE

I need to access it from web applications.  So I need to send an sql query to databse and get the list of material types from the attribute domain. Is this possible? Or should I not use the domains and subtypes.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what exact version of ArcGIS is in use. You have this tagged 10.0 which was retired years ago (10.1 will be retired next week). While retirement doesn't stop continued use, it does decrease the likelihood that anyone else is still using the software, so not only don't you get Support or security patches, you're less likely to get help in informal support mechanisms as well.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Which exact PostgreSQL release are you using? You hsve ArcGIS Server tagged - Are you you using a Feature Service to update the table?

Comment: using postgresql 9.5

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: edited  the post

Comment: I don't have a postgresql installation handy right now, but in SQL Server, the domains are stored in an XML column in a table called dbo.gdb_items. I suspect SDE uses a similar table in Postgresql, probably in the 'sde' schema.

Answer (score 2):

To find the domains you will have to access them from GDB_ITEMS table and join it to the GDB_ITEMTYPES table:

```
SELECT items.name AS "Domain Name",
 (xpath('//Owner/text()', definition))[1]::text as "Owner"
FROM sde.gdb_items AS items INNER JOIN sde.gdb_itemtypes AS itemtypes
ON items.type = itemtypes.uuid
WHERE itemtypes.name IN ('Coded Value Domain', 'Range Domain');
```

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/example-finding-domain-owners.htm

To return coded domain values in MSSQL:

```
   SELECT
   codedValue.value('Code[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS "Code",
   codedValue.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS "Value"
   FROM
   dbo.GDB_ITEMS AS items INNER JOIN dbo.GDB_ITEMTYPES AS itemtypes
   ON items.Type = itemtypes.UUID
   CROSS APPLY
   items.Definition.nodes
   ('/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue') AS CodedValues(codedValue)
```

Comment: first query returns domain list but how can I get the domain contents?

Comment: Ive edited the answer to show how to return domian contents, but its on MSSQL. you should be able to convert it to postgreSQL by chaning lines 2 and 3. I run MSSQL so I cant convert it and verify.